# How to completely opt-out of interactive dismissal of presented view controller in iOS 13 Xcode 11 builds?

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, xcode11

I am trying to build my existing code with Xcode 11. I see a weird behavior the view controllers,

[image]
 - Looks like the View controllers have a different modalPresentationStyle (interactive dismissal)

I see some options on internet to fix this

1. `viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen`
2. `viewController.isModalInPresentation = true`

But is there a way to completely opt out of this behavior, I am looking for a minimal code change to handle it across the whole app.

Comment: Don't opt-out. Embrace the new features of iOS 13. But if you really want, you need to use of the two options you have posted for each and every view controller you present in your app. There is no global opt-out (for a reason).

Comment: Agree and I would love to embrace the new features, but until we figure out all the changes I wanted to be able to run the code on XCode 11 to test iPhone 11's with iOS  13